# How can I prevent a package from opening when starting a RStudio project

Tags: rstudio, package, startup, lmertest

I have the lmerTest package installed, but it masks some of the lme4 functions and it loads automatically when I start a specific project.

I have tried deleteing the package but now I just get an error:

> Loading required package: lmerTest Error in .requirePackage(package) :
>   unable to find required package ‘lmerTest’ In addition: Warning
>   message: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,
>   logical.return = TRUE,  :   there is no package called ‘lmerTest’

Every time I open Rstudio it attempts to load the lmerTest package. The error message repeats ten times.

I have checked the Rprofile file but it is not in there.

This seems to be the same problem: 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200798587-How-can-I-prevent-a-package-from-trying-to-load-at-startup-

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution here is to delete (or 'hide') the .RData file from the folder.

In the terminal you could do the following, assuming the terminal is open in the working directory.

`mv ./.RData ./.RData_old`

This should get RStudio opening without that package loading but all your other objects will not be there either. If you still have the code used to create the objects, you'd just need to run through it again to create all the objects again.

Comment: Loading .RData might be cause for somebody's problem, but in my case it keep loading a package even I don't have .RData saved or loaded. In the end I have to clean up the RStudio desktop folder, which probably corrupted a little bit in my upgrading from R 3.5.0 to R 3.5.1. `mv ~/.rstudio-desktop ~/backup-rstudio-desktop`